# Где можно протестировать мобильную версию письма?

Tags: html, css, рассылка

Делаю почтовую рассылку. Нужно протестировтать, как будет выглядеть на смартфоне, а у меня есть только планшет, но в приложении gmail отображается только десктопная версия (широковат планшет). Не нашёл способ повлиять на разрешение. 
Может есть какой-то сервис, чтобы я потестил это дело на компе ?

Answer (score 0):

Искал ответы на вопрос, нашел рекомендацию сайта [Litmus](https://litmus.com/). Возможно подойдет, правда регистрацию требует.

Comment: Спасибо, буду изучать.